# Proving that ϱ is a metric?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I have an Analysis exam coming soon, and found this practice problem a bit challenging. 
Any help on this would be appreciated.

> A metric space $M$ with metric $d$ can always be re-metrized so the metric space becomes bounded. Simply define the bounded metric:
>   $$
> \varrho(p,q) = \frac{d(p,q)}{1+d(p,q)}
> $$
>   Prove that $\varrho$ is a metric. Why is it obviously bounded?

Comment: A simpler equivalent bounded metric is $\delta(p,q)=\min\{d(p,q),1\}$.

Comment: @David 's answer shows it's bounded and $\rho(p,q)\leq \mathrm{d}(p,q)$. So if you know another bound such that $\alpha\cdot\rho(p,q)\geq \mathrm{d}(p,q)$, then the metrics are equivalent in terms of their open sets

Answer (score 2):

For any $x\geq0$, we have $$\frac{x}{1+x}<1.$$